# How to clean up the theme for production?

Tags: theme-development, customization, production

Is there some automated way to generate a dist/production version of the theme without all of the hidden .git, IDE directories and the config files, node_modules?

```
WARNING: .babelrc .git .gitignore .idea .sass-cache .bin .npmignore .github .travis.yml .coveralls.yml .eslintrc .gitattributes .jshintrc .verb.md Hidden Files or Folders found.

REQUIRED: Please remove any extraneous directories like .git or .svn from the ZIP file before uploading it.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use gulp zip to do that. Take a look here https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-zip. This will let you zip up your theme with a terminal command and you can ignore whichever folders you want.